# how to make ajax work on search input?

Tags: php, ajax

This is my code in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getSearch(str){

        if(str.length == 0){
        status.innerHTML =  'field is empty';
      }
if(u != "")
  {

        var se = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

urlencoded");

```
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

        }
      }

  }
</script>
```

I am trying to make a live search so that when the person introduces a character in the input,it displays the movies from the database,the 'field is empty' and 'Verifying...' messages are displayed properly,but when i type something nothing changes insted of those messages.Can someone tell me please what can i do to fix it ?

In my console it says: Uncaught ReferenceError: xmlhttp is not defined

Comment: Any trace in your browser's console ?

Comment: it says: Uncaught ReferenceError: xmlhttp is not defined

Comment: where are you defining xmlhttp?

Comment: search **xmlhttp is not defined**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your js code: variable `xmlhttp` is not defined, you probably mean `se` instead. Try to replace

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange
```

by

```
se.onreadystatechange
```

Comment: The script works now but when i type something the page appears again on top of the other one on the screen.any idea how can i fix that ?